# Can value for win32_computersystemproduct be changed?

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

i have need to change win32_computersystemproduct property values to something otherthan what they are set to right now. Also this is for Windows 7 in a Parallels VM on MAC.

Can someone point me to right direction, if this is possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As is clearly documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), none of the properties of `Win32_ComputerSystemProduct` can be set through the WMI class. I believe these values are derived from the BIOS, so you may be able to change them there. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I moved my Windows 7 (Toshiba Protege R700) to Parallels 6 VM on MAC OSx10.7. And the HArdware details in my Virtual machine (for this class) are being setup differently than the values on my toshiba Laptop. I know hardware is different but for me its important to have same hardware specs so that i can connect using the windows VM on my network.

Comment: Yep. Your BIOS completely changed to a virtual BIOS. You may want to ask how this information can be tweaked in Parallels on [superuser.com]. I really don't see how this affects your ability to connect to the network (does your network do scans for a pre-defined list of SKUs?). Ultimately, though, there is no programming solution to this problem.